# Is the GitHub API down or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, github, github3.py

I am attempting to use the github3 Python API and am encountering authentication errors when attempting to acess profile information.
To reproduce (after `sudo pip install github3.py`):

```
    from github3 import login

    github = login("username", "password")

    user = github.me()
```

Comment: Use a Personal Access Token instead of username and password. Learn how to generate a PAT here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token and use the code `login(token="xxx...")`.

Comment: @Seth I have an application that asks for a users' GitHub username and password. Is there a way to turn that into a PAT on-the-fly?

Comment: Authorize your application via the OAuth web flow. https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authorizing-oauth-apps

Comment: Specifically, you should probably use the OAuth Device Flow as shown here: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#device-flow

Comment: @Seth Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Seth Can github3 do this? I'm not sure how to set this up.

Comment: github3 doesn't have to. Just create POST requests to the endpoints specified in the documentation I sent. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp

Comment: @Seth Interesting! I feel like this should be part of github3 itself. Maybe I'll add the code.